# Set Limit for a Table Rows In SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to set the limit for my table's rows. How can I do it?

For example 50 rows in my table.

Comment: What do you want to do when it hits 51? Not allow them to insert it, or remove #1?

Comment: Unusual requirement. Possibly look at instead of triggers on your insert and then discard if rowcount > 50?

Comment: Perhaps you want to limit number of rows returned by a specific query?

Comment: Hey Doozer, what if thwas the case? I am after that option.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Create an `AFTER INSERT` trigger on the table.  Here's something that would be relatively effective with your requirement:

```
create trigger LimitTable
on YourTableToLimit
after insert
as
    declare @tableCount int
    select @tableCount = Count(*)
    from YourTableToLimit

    if @tableCount > 50
    begin
        rollback
    end
go
```

Comment: -1 That assumes the application does not have a transaction control itself (Autocommit). This would break the app's if the `INSERT` is, say, the 3rd data change query in a chain of, say, 5 queries.

Comment: This can fail under snapshot isolation.

Comment: @MartinSmith I understand that, but given the information the OP provided, this is the solution I came up with.  There are obviously a few "gotchas" with certain configuration, but without knowing if they exist this is my best guess for a solution.

Comment: this doesn't work for idea to have max 50, so 51th row would unshift the first value but would be added

Answer (score 6):

Use a CHECK constraint. E.g.:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (x TINYINT NOT NULL UNIQUE CHECK (x BETWEEN 1 AND 50));
```

Comment: Interesting approach, I like your "thinking outside the box". However, who would be responsible for giving `x` a value? Only this will determine if your approach will work.

Comment: I'm manging a queue so maybe it can be an IDENTITY and reseed when cleaning, ritgh? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Are you referring to limiting the results of a query?

If so, with SQL Server 2008 you can use `TOP`

```
SELECT TOP 50 *
FROM Table
```

If you're looking at actually limiting the amount of records in the database table, then an IF statement in a `TRIGGER`, like [@Shark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7930286/set-limit-for-a-table-rows-in-sql/7930321#7930321) has posted, would be my solution.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is having a `INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger that checks the # of current rows. If already 50, you will raise an error by using [`RAISERROR`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx). If not, you just `insert` the record.

> **Warning!** Untested code ahead. It might contain typos or slight syntax errors. The code is supposed to show you the concepts involved. Tweak and adjust to your needs accordingly.

Like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER checktablelimit 
ON yourtable 
INSTEAD OF INSERT 
AS 
  DECLARE @currentCount INT 

  SELECT @currentCount = COUNT(*) 
  FROM   yourtabletolimit 

  IF @currentCount = 50 
    BEGIN 
        RAISERROR ('Table already has 50 records', 
                   11, 
                   1); 
    END 
  ELSE 
    BEGIN 
        INSERT INTO yourtable 
                    (field1, 
                     field2, 
                     field3) 
        SELECT field1, 
               field2, 
               field3 
        FROM   inserted 
    END 

GO
```

Comment: This won't be reliable if more than one row is inserted in a single INSERT statement.

Comment: Also it won't handle concurrent inserts. 2 transactions could both do `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM yourtabletolimit` and read that value and determine that their insert won't breach the limit.

Comment: @dportas You are also right. Damn it, apparently SQL Server does not have a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger. This is so easily handled by Oracle, Firebird, PostgreSQL... Of course, they do not solve the point raised by @MartinSmith. I'll leave my answer here, maybe someone can see further on the top of it.

Comment: @Adrian - Shame there are so many restrictions on indexed views as well. I was trying to think of a way of using one of those with a unique constraint but foiled at every attempt!

Comment: @MartinSmith I liked dportas' approach (unique constraint), I just don't see how to make it work as well...